# How to customize the "BarcodeScanner" in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I am facing an issue in customizing the design for (QR code scan screen) in ionic 3 which exists in ionic BarcodeScanner library.
I need help in customizing this screen, add header, footer, and buttons.
In the attachment, there is a screen shot for the design and screen shot for the QR code scan in ionic.

Appreciate your help guys.

[image: the QR code scan screen and the design which I want to use]

Comment: You will have to fork the original plugin and modify the native design of the camera-overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fork the original plug-in from

> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/ios/scannerOverlay.xib

for IOS or the respective one for android and modify camera overlay with android and xml. **See example:**

> https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner

Comment: your response is correct. For those who doubt it, check the response from a community moderator on the ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-barcode-scanner-overlay-img-when-scanning/86095/4?u=guithomas